# How to get JUST the Elasticsearch server version from the command line

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, command-line-interface

Is there way to get JUST the version number for an Elasticsearch server. I know you get the JSON request data but is there a way to parse that request get the version number only.

*curl localhost:9200*

```
{
    ...
    "version": {
        ...
        "number": "2.1.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) utility, you can use it to parse the json reply and output a plain text string:

```
curl -sS localhost:9200 | jq -r .version.number
```

General purpose scripting languages can accomplish the same, but are usually more clunky:

```
curl -sS localhost:9200 | python -c 'import json, sys; print(json.loads(sys.stdin.read())["version"]["number"])'
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way that doesn't require any outside dependencies is to use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/common-options.html#_response_filtering) and the `filter_path` query string parameter (available since ES 1.6) and the `awk` command.

```
curl -s -XGET 'localhost:9200?filter_path=version.number&pretty=false' | awk -F'"' {'print $6'}
```

That returns:

```
2.1.1
```