# How to get the Elasticserch version using the Elasticsearch ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

The Elasticsearch ruby gem (defined [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby)) doesn't seem to expose a method for getting the Elasticsearch version on the cluster to which you are connecting.  (Though I might just be missing it.)

Is there a way to do so from the gem (other than curling port 9200, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822244/) )?

Answer (score 8):

You're missing it.

It's [`Elasticsearch::API::Actions.info`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/Elasticsearch/API/Actions#info-instance_method)

> Return simple information about the cluster (name, version).

I believe this would suffice for localhost on port 9200:

```
require 'elasticsearch'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true

client.info
```

Comment: specifically, version is at `client.info['version']['number']`

Comment: This was so incredibly frustrating to find. All the docs they have, and none of them clearly show how to do a health check and list the version. Abysmal.